# Python: create a list of datetime.date type efficiently, like "lubridate" in R

Tags: python, r, lubridate

In R, I can create a vector containing dates, like this:

```
# R
library(lubridate)
fivedays = today() - 1:5
```

which gives:

```
Output:
> fivedays
 [1] "2020-07-26" "2020-07-25" "2020-07-24" "2020-07-23" "2020-07-22"
```

What will be the most efficient way to achieve similar result, in python?

I have attempted to do it, like this:

```py
# python
import datetime
oneday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
```

above works for one day only.
below is a pseude-code, I wish it worked.

```py
# python
import datetime
fivedays = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days = [x for x in range(1,6)])

# Above fails with following error
# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: list
```

Comment: Our team has been mainly working in R, but welcoming new members soon who are more python inclined. I'm trying to close the gap between my knowledge in R and wisdom of python coders. many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the `numpy` module:

```
import numpy as np
fivedays = np.datetime64('today') - np.arange(1, 6)
```

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the numpy method as being closest in concept to R's vector notation.
This has been a great excise for me to learn and adjust my thinking in R to familiarise myself with python.

thank you again and please have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension like the following is probably the closest you'll get to the "vector" syntax in your question.

```
today = datetime.date.today()
fivedays = [today - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(5)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant re-write of my non-working code!
It is a great help for me to re-learn a new syntax of python, sure will look into learning more about list comprehension. Hope you will have a lovely day!